# How to acces a JSON key that looks like this: { ' "TimePeriod"': '2019-05-15'

Tags: node.js, json, string, parsing

I am new to coding and learning a lot these days. I got stuck at a recent problem which I could not solve with the help of Google. I get a JSON from an API call. I parsed it, saved it to myObject and it looks like this:

```
{ 
  '"TimePeriod"': '2019-05-15',
  AveragePosition: '3.25',
  ConversionRate: '0',
  CostPerAssist: '0',
}
```

As you can see, the word `TimePeriod` is surrounded but single- AND doublequotes. One strange finding is, that when I copy the JSON from the console it add a empty string to it which is not visible within the console: `' "TimePeriod"'`

I tried to access it like an array:

```
myObject["TimePeriod"];
myObject['"TimePeriod"'];
myObject[' "TimePeriod"'];
myObject['\"TimePeriod\"']
myObject['\'\"TimePeriod\"\'']
```

etc. but I cannot get the date value 2019-05-15. I obviously can access all other values below the first TimePeriod one.

What I get back for the `TimePeriod` is always: `undefined`.

Comment: You can escape `"` like `myObject['\"TimePeriod\"']`, but it's weird you get it with quotes around

Comment: I already tried exactly this one, but it also gives me an undefined

Comment: on browser or nodejs? It's working fine in my case

Comment: on nodejs, my goal is to save all the json values into a mysql db.

Comment: I see that in the browser it is also working for me, but not within NodeJS. Does somebody have any idea how to make it work in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest iterating over the object to get the values.  You can do this via for...in :

```
for(var prop in myObject) {
  console.log(myObject[prop])
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

Given that object one correct way of getting that property is `['"TimePeriod"']`.

See

```
({ 
  '"TimePeriod"': '2019-05-15',
  AveragePosition: '3.25',
  ConversionRate: '0',
  CostPerAssist: '0',
})['"TimePeriod"']
```

yields

```
"2019-05-15"
```